# After angular filter on options if only one option is left, select it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have two select boxes. One of the boxes takes what the other one has selected and uses it as a filter for itself. Sometimes that filter only leaves one option.  I am looking for a way to auto select that option only if it is the only one in the list.

If this is too vague I can put in an example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular related question. But here is the answer using jQuery:

```
    var numitems=$('#myselect').children('option').length;
    if(numitems == 1) {
        $("#myselect option:first").attr('selected','selected');  // just select the first
    }
```

You can also select by value if you know the value
        $('[name=myselect]').val( 3 );  // Select by a value== 3

You can also select by text.